# Notation for a Line Segment

Tags: notation

I have a straight line segment joining two points ($i$ and $j$). I have a third point, $k$, that has a perpendicular distance to the line segment $\kappa_{\bot}$ (call this line segment of length $\kappa_{\bot}$ "*").

What exactly is the best notation to use to describe this line segment (*)? Is there an "official" way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It's the [altitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)) relative to $[ij]$ in the triangle $ijk$.

Comment: so what's the best notation?

Comment: Let $h=proj_{(ij)}k$ then this segment is $[ih]=[i proj_{(ij)}k]$.

Comment: There are other notations perhaps but why not define a notation for this line segment like $\perp_{(ij)}k$ or $\perp(k, (ij))$ and use it.

Comment: I'm using $h_{\mathbf{r}_{ij}}$, mainly because altitude uses $h$.